# Не меняется кодировка текста

Tags: delphi, кодировка, utf-8

Добрый вечер ХэшКодЧане ^^

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Мне нужно записать в текстовый файл строки в кодировке UTF-8
Программа создает XML-файл, занося в него строки таким образом

```
WriteLn(XmlFile, ansitoutf8('<field name="Field1">привет</field>'));
```

Однако в результате получается никакой не UTF8, и при открытии файла через браузер получаем ошибки:

```
Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML: некорректно
Адрес: file:///G:/adverts2.xml
Строка %№_строки%, символ 22:       
<field name="Field1">������</field>
---------------------^
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Декларацию xml указали?

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: да, указал. и браузер показывает, что это страница имеет кодировку UTF-8

Comment: Страница может быть в UTF, а вот текст в файле по какой-то причине совсем не UTF.

Comment: проверил, у меня даже без указания encoding браузер отображает верно, срабатывает автоопределение. генерил файл на d7. hex редактор показывает двубайтные русские буквы, т.е. все ок. кстати, какой браузер выдает такую ошибку?

Comment: firefox 9.x.x

Comment: понятно. в FF11 норм. в других safari, ie, opera тоже ок. видимо надо искать инфу по ff9 конкретно, с файлом скорее всего все нормально.

Comment: суть не в том, чтобы открыть файл в браузере, а в том, чтобы делфи нормально перекодировало текст.

Comment: Ну а нафига тогда открывать файл в браузере? Откройте самым простым редактором, умеющим показывать кодировку.

Comment: mother of God... вместо того, чтобы помочь решить проблему, вы мне рассказываете, как посмотреть кодировку текста в файле?

Comment: > mother of God... вместо того, чтобы помочь решить проблему, вы мне рассказываете, как посмотреть кодировку текста в файле?

А это уж вы сами виноваты, завели речь про браузеры и фирефоксы, вместо того, чтобы четко сказать, что строка пишется в файл в неверной кодировке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всем спасибо, все свободны

```
str.SaveToFile('G:\Test.xml',Tencoding.UTF8); // где str - переменная типа TStringlist
```

Comment: А раньше в выдаче гугла найти это было сложно самому?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте файл в hex редакторе и посмотрите, как именно закодирован неверный текст. Подозреваю, что там вставлены маркеры (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Посмотрите на первый байт - его не нашло в таблице символов и подставило код. Который, судя по всему - 0xffff - а это не совсем нормальный символ для utf-8. "uffffufffdufffdufffdufffdufffdufffd" - это в целом плохая последовательность для utf-8 либо браузер исказил.

WriteLn вообще то может и не работать с utf-8 строкой. Я понимаю, что к нему привыкли и оно удобно, но попробуйте использовать TFileStream и переписать с ним (не объязательно весь проект - можно сделать себе демку).

Также проверьте, что бы Вы не писали адрес переменной вместо самого содержимого:)

Comment: Просто функция ansitoutf8() нормально работает только с первыми 128 символами ascii. поэтому я по-другому подошел к решению проблемы и использовал метод TStringlist - savetofile, в котором можно выбрать тип кодировки, который в свою очередь нормально воспринимает все символы.

Comment: Функция работает правильно - она преобразовывает символы с кодами больше 128 согласно текущей кодировки системы. Но если неверно использовать...

И я не говорил, что нужно в блокноте смотреть. Нужно именно в хекс редакторе смотреть. тогда будет понятее. Он просто не искажает.